# Books on random permutations

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, reference-request, quantum-mechanics, percolation

I'm looking for books or introductory/expository articles about random permutations, in particular with regards to their cycle structure.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm especially interested in spatial aspects of random permutations. A couple of relevant keywords: Ewen's sampling formula, Feller coupling, Bose-Einstein condensate, and, to a lesser degree, percolations.

Comment: Chapter 6 of "Combinatorics of permutations", Miklós Bóna works out 2-cycle permutations.

Comment: @Phicar: Thanks. It's a good resource. However, browsing through this chapter I've realized I didn't specify what I was looking for well enough. So I've edited my original message with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Logarithmic Combinatorial Structures: A Probabilistic Approach" by Arratia, Tavaré and Barbour. European Mathematical Society (2003)

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTIONS WILL BE GLADLY ACCEPTED